# Parse JSON with hashtag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In Javascript, I'm having trouble parse this **JSON** that has a "#" in it. I want to get an image URL.

My attempt was: `tracks.track[0].image[0].#track`

The # is screwing me up....

```
{
tracks: {
track: [
{
name: "Stressed Out",
duration: "0",
playcount: "1516304",
listeners: "186543",
mbid: "",
url: "http://www.last.fm/music/Twenty+One+Pilots/_/Stressed+Out",
streamable: {
#text: "0",
fulltrack: "0"
},
artist: {
name: "Twenty One Pilots",
mbid: "a6c6897a-7415-4f8d-b5a5-3a5e05f3be67",
url: "http://www.last.fm/music/Twenty+One+Pilots"
},
image: [
{
#text: "http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/34s/5c3d2c588ae38b7ff192f6b4cec71170.png",
size: "small"
},
{
#text: "http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/64s/5c3d2c588ae38b7ff192f6b4cec71170.png",
size: "medium"
},
```

Comment: That is not JSON. [JSON](http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159) needs to have keys quoted.

Comment: Correcto...its just a good 'ol JS object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
tracks.track[0].image[0]['#text']
```

[Check it in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awy91ezn/1/)

<sup>*Note that I'm adding the quotes using a regex to parse the string*</sup>

PS: You wrote `tracks.track[0].image[0].#track` but I'm assuming `#text`, since I don't see any `#track` in the JSON... if you really mean `#track`, then change as appropiate*